# Error using Create Table DDL

Tags: ms-access, ddl, create-table

My goal is to store 15-minute interval data in a (as of now) stand alone Access database.  Databases aren't my area of expertise, but I'm giving it a go.  I found a set of metadata data files that contain DDL in Oracle format that are designed to create relational tables and primary / foreign keys.  I am currently trying to use these DDL files to create the database structure and am getting the following syntax error: Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement

The very first portion of the DDL is listed below:

```
create table AGGOUTPUTHEADER
(
  UIDAGGOUTPUTHEADER NUMBER(19) not null,
  SAVERECORDER       VARCHAR2(128) not null,
  SAVECHANNEL        NUMBER(6) not null,
  QSECODE            VARCHAR2(64),
  UIDBILLDETERMINANT NUMBER(19) not null,
  UIDSETLPOINT       NUMBER(19),
  RESOURCEID         VARCHAR2(64),
  GENSITECODE        VARCHAR2(64),
  NOIECODE           VARCHAR2(64),
  PGCCODE            VARCHAR2(64),
  TDSPCODE           VARCHAR2(64),
  UIDRESOURCE        NUMBER(19),
  UFEZONECODE        VARCHAR2(64),
  LSTIME             DATE
);
```

It's entirely possible I'm asking the wrong questions here - I'm mostly just looking for some high level guidance re: how to get started.

Comment: Can you post the syntax error?

Comment: @User...Also, is this SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL?

Comment: @MikeTWebb : It's Oracle as tagged such immediately below the question body.

Comment: I have copy & pasted your DDL statement into Oracle 10g, it worked with no problem at all and created the respective table (without modification to the DDL statement at all).

Comment: Apologies, but I'm extremely new to this.  I'm adding this into a blank Access db and am not sure of the server type.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @Lion...thanks, yeah I just noticed that :)

Comment: You'll need to figure out which database Access is using. `VARCHAR2` is specific to Oracle - SQL Server and MySQL want `VARCHAR` without the "2" at the end. `NUMBER` is also not supported on SQL Server or MySQL - they want `NUMERIC` instead.

Comment: OK.  How do I figure that part out?

Comment: *what* syntax error?  Being new to this is no excise for not posting basic information, information without which we cannot help you.

Comment: @APC Error says "Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement"

Comment: Well *that's* helpful 8-(  Although at least we can tell it's not an Oracle error message.

Comment: Exactly why I didn't post it in the first place.  What kind of info do you need from me?

Comment: @APC maybe this should be retagged as an Access question? user2175516 - try replacing VARCHAR2 with VARCHAR and NUMBER with NUMERIC and see if you have any luck. Also try with and without the semicolon at the end. If that doesn't work we may not be able to help - an Access forum might be better.

Comment: @graceemile - thank you. still no luck - seems to be getting hung up on the NUMBER/NUMERIC(19) portion.  Doesn't like the parenthetical.

Comment: @user2175516 : See [Access Datatypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714540(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @user2175516 Please edit your question to give us some context. You are apparently trying to "create a new database using already-provided DDL", but based on the comments to date the DDL is clearly not intended to create a new native Access database. Do you want to create a stand-alone Access database, or do you want to create an Access database with linked tables to an Oracle server?

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you for the response.  I've edited my question and have hopefully provided a little more context.

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site.  If you don't even know what question to ask how can we provide an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use syntax suitable for MS Access to create a table in MS Access, for example, you would get away with this:

```
create table AGGOUTPUTHEADER
(
  UIDAGGOUTPUTHEADER NUMBER  not null,
  SAVERECORDER       VARCHAR(128) not null,
  SAVECHANNEL        NUMBER not null,
  QSECODE            VARCHAR(64),
  UIDBILLDETERMINANT NUMBER not null,
  UIDSETLPOINT       NUMBER,
  RESOURCEID         VARCHAR(64),
  GENSITECODE        VARCHAR(64),
  NOIECODE           VARCHAR(64),
  PGCCODE            VARCHAR(64),
  TDSPCODE           VARCHAR(64),
  UIDRESOURCE        NUMBER,
  UFEZONECODE        VARCHAR(64),
  LSTIME             DATE
);
```

if you must use examples from a different database, at least look for SQL Server, because it is much closer to MS Access.

Number will give you a double data type and varchar a text data type.

You may find some of these helpful:

[Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx)
[Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)
[Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)